# Почему FOR XML возвращает неправильный формат?

Tags: sql-server, xml, exec

Есть процедура, которая по предназначению должна возвращать XML.
Сам код:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[get_customer_info](@id_customer int)
as
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @Database_Settings VARCHAR(500)
    SET @Database_Settings = (SELECT dbo.MIB_Get_settings_value ('Database_Settings'))
    Declare @sa varchar(500)
    set @sa ='
      select First_name
     , Last_name
     , Father_name
     , Birth_date
     , Country
     , Region
     , village
     , Adress
     , Tel_mob
     , Tel_home
     , Sex
     , Marital_status 
     , Family_name
     , Family_count
     , Series_doc
     , Num_doc
     , Date_doc
     , Issue_doc
     , Tax_number
     , Nationality
     , Education
     , Map_long
     , Map_latit
       from' + @Database_Settings + 'CUSTOMER where ID='+CONVERT(varchar(20),@id_customer)+' for xml path ' ;
Exec (@sa) AT [ABS\SERVER];
END
```

Код до места "***for xml path***" возвращает нужную мне таблицу.
Выше описанный код после **exec** возвращает длинную строку, вместо нужного мне xml:

[image: пример]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что и где я делаю не так?

Comment: А если так попробовать: `Exec (@sa) AT [ABS\SERVER] WITH RESULT SETS (AS FOR XML);` ?

Comment: @i-one - ругается: EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 column(s) for result set number 1, but the statement sent 23 column(s) at run time.

Comment: _"ругается: ... WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 column(s) for result set number 1, but the statement sent 23"_ - вы убрали `for xml path` из запроса? Не нужно было, оставьте как было и попробуйте добавить `AS FOR XML` к exec.

Comment: @i-one, я не менял...

Comment: Вот msg ошибки: `EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified type 'ntext' for column #1 in result set #1, and the corresponding type sent at run time was 'image'; there is no conversion between the two types.`

Comment: Вот тут ([ссылка](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/440179bf-ce9c-4cb5-af74-f84fa89dc34e)) нашлось похожее. Вообще с передачей xml через linked server проблема (которая становится явной, при использовании `for xml path, type`). Т.е. видимо да, либо через linked server получать данные, а `for xml` делать на принимающей стороне, либо на отдающей стороне явно конвертировать xml в бинарный формат, а на принимающей делать обратную конвертацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел оптимальный ответ, который удовлетворяет меня, может кому пригодиться...

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[get_customer_info](@id_customer int)
as
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @Database_Settings VARCHAR(500)
     DECLARE @finalQuery VARCHAR(800)
    SET @Database_Settings = (SELECT dbo.MIB_Get_settings_value ('Database_Settings'))
    Declare @sa varchar(8000)
    set @sa ='
      select 
       First_name
     , Last_name
     , Father_name
     , Birth_date
     , Country
     , Region
     , village
     , Adress
     , Tel_mob
     , Tel_home
     , Sex
     , Marital_status 
     , Family_name
     , Family_count
     , Series_doc
     , Num_doc
     , Date_doc
     , Issue_doc
     , Tax_number
     , Nationality
     , Education
     , Map_long
     , Map_latit
       from ' + @Database_Settings + 'CUSTOMER where ID='+CONVERT(varchar(20),@id_customer);

    SET @finalQuery = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([ABS\SERVER],'
                        + '''' + @sa + '''' + ') as t for xml path'

    EXEC(@finalQuery)
END 


  -- exec get_customer_info '100002'
```